# Connecting to a service hosted on HTTPS server with Apache httpclient and key store information.

Tags: java, apache, httpclient, keystore

I am developing an integration project and at runtime my component would be connecting to a service hosted on HTTPS server. Now to connect to this server I would be downloading the certificate for this server, importing the same to the system.jks  of my server (where my application would be running). At runtime while connecting to the service (hosted on HTTPS server) which I do using Apache HTTPClient I want the system.jks to be looked up for the certificate.

I have not handled this so far and I am getting 403 forbidden error. Could you please suggest how to handle this.

Thanks,
Rakesh

Comment: Is there client certificate authentication? Because 403 means that access is denied. It is not SSL connection error. Btw is apache server certificate self signed or signed by public authority like Verisign?

Comment: @Leos: Yes. By default (in absence of coding for where to lookup for the certificate) application server JDK cacerts file is being looked up for the certificate. But the problem is each time application is restarted the certificate needs to be included in the cacerts which is not desired. Now I want to include the certificate in the system.jks.

Comment: Take a look at http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientCustomSSL.java